# How to continue custom dataTable after DataTable().row.add()?

Tags: javascript, datatable, datatables

I've already initialized dataTable once when i do DataTable().row.add(), but i still need to do some extra methods with that datatable. For example, i need to do this api method:
`$('#example').DataTable( { dom: 'Bfrtip', buttons: [ 'colvis' ] } );`
but there is an alert *DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable* for every rows i have in my datatables, it means if i have 10 rows, this alert will show 10 times, althought after i skip all these alert, everything looks fine then, and there is no error in the console,too
Here is my code:

*following some comments below, i've **UPDATED** my code*

```
            var myTable = $('#dataTable').DataTable({ dom: 'Bfrtip', buttons: ['colvis'] });
            var row = $('#dataTable tbody tr:first');
            myTable.row.add([
                '<img width="70px" height="100px" src="' + childData.poster + '">',
                '<p style="height:100px;overflow:auto;text-align:center">' + childData.title + '</p>',
                '<a style="text-align:center" href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="showModalListChapter(' + "'" + childKey + "'" + "," + "'" + childData.title + "'" + ')">' + totalChapters + '</a>',
                '<p style="height:100px;overflow:auto;text-align:center">' + childData.author + '</p>',
                '<p style="width:100px;height:100px;overflow:auto;text-align:center">' + childData.category + '</p>',
                '<p style="text-align:center">' + childData.state + '</p>',
                '<p style="width:350px;height:100px;overflow:auto;text-align:center">' + childData.description + '</p>',
                '<p style="text-align:center">' + childData.totalViews + '</p>',
                '<p style="text-align:center">' + childData.totalLikes + '</p>',
                '<button class="btn btn-danger" style="margin-bottom:20px" onclick="deleteManga(' + "'" + childKey + "'" + ')">xóa</button>' +
                '<button class="btn btn-warning" onclick="showModalUpdateManga(' + "'" + childKey + "'" + ')">sửa</button>',
                '<p style="text-align:center">' + childData.createdDate + '</p>',
                '<p style="text-align:center">' + childData.updatedDate + '</p>',
            ]).draw(false);
```

The same problem still happens

Comment: Please update your question and add in your code segment.

Comment: You've updated your question and added that you're now getting an error, so the question has changed... But that error indicates that you have something else in your code that you're not showing us, where you're initializing the DataTable again.  It should not be caused by adding a row.

Comment: I've updated my answer below with a link to a demo that shows a re-initialized error is now caused by simply adding a row.  It looks like you need to debug your code and find the other call that is initializing that datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely (hard to say for 100% because you haven't given us your code segment), you need to init the datatable to a variable, and then use the object in that variable to add your rows.  So:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myTable = $('#example').DataTable( { dom: 'Bfrtip', buttons: [ 'colvis' ] } ); 
    //and then, under some condition, and likely inside a function:
     myTable.row.add(data);
} );
```

The [DataTables documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) on `row.add()` has further examples.

**UPDATE**

Here is a Fiddle demo that shows the basics for initializing a Datatable and then adding a row:  https://jsfiddle.net/zephyr_hex/enkmhb2t/13/

Comment: i've found something looks like a solution in the document you shared
`var table = $('#example').DataTable();
 
var rowNode = table
    .row.add( [ 'Fiona White', 32, 'Edinburgh' ] )
    .draw()
    .node();
 
$( rowNode )
    .css( 'color', 'red' )
    .animate( { color: 'black' } );`
but the problem is i don't need any use of adding css or animate, i need to use api method about visibility of column [Basic column visibility](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/simple.html)

Comment: @NgôTrọngPhúc : Then don't add the css.  There's no requirement that you do.  The documentation shows that `row.add()` accepts a data parameter, and it shows an example of how to do that... you don't have to use the css or the animate.  Just follow my example and replace "data" with properly formatted data...

Comment: @NgôTrọngPhúc : I've added a link to a demo that shows the basics for how to initialize a DataTable and then add a row, which answers your original question before you changed it to something different.

Comment: i've followed the demo you shared and i've updated my code in the question,it is my latest code now but there's still the alert, this alert show for every row i have in the datatable,meaning if i had 10 rows,it would show that alert 10 times. Althought after i skip all of that alert,everything looks fine,there's no error in console,too.But now everytime i reload the page,i have to skip all the alert of datatables